# Close/hide the background command window in Electron JS?

Tags: javascript, electron

Trying to figure out how to run Electron in its own process, separate from the caller.

I have an Electron app that runs a small ReactJS web form. When I go to launch Electron, the caller won't return until I close the Electron window, therefore forcing me to keep this extra calling window around.

Launch steps:

```
1) Open a new Command Prompt (cmd.exe):    
2) start /b npm.cmd start
```

When I do this, the Command Prompt WAITS indefinitely, until the Electron window closes. As such, I have to have TWO windows open, which isn't ideal on a Production environment (I'd like the user to click a *.bat file on their desktop, on for JUST the Electron window to pop up; not a CMD.exe window AND the Electron window).

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Can't you just run your app executable directly? Or if you need to pass in arguments do so via a shortcut.